# determinant of an $ n\times n$ matrix type

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the following determinants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84206/how-to-calculate-the-following-determinants)
>   [Computing determinant of a specific matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165816/computing-determinant-of-a-specific-matrix)

How can one compute the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix where all the diagonal entries are equal to $0$ and all the off-diagonal entries are equal to $1$?

Comment: This question is certainly a duplicate of several others, which I has no time to look up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the $n\times n$ matrix of all ones.  The rank of $A$ is 1, and it can be seen that the vector of all ones is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $n$, so the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $t^{n-1}(t-n)$.  If $B$ denotes your matrix, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\det(B)&=&\det(A-1)\\
&=&(-1)^n\det(1-A)\\
&=&(-1)^n(t^{n-1}(t-n))|_{t=1}\\
&=&(-1)^n(1-n)
\end{eqnarray*}