# Simple solution to computing the eigenvalues/vectors of $N \times N$ matrix with diagonal entries $N$ and off-diagonal entries 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Versions of this question have been asked before ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175228/), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904926/)). However, I am asking again for two reasons:

1. My question is slightly different—it's about eigenvalues/vectors, not determinants—, and I don't know enough linear algebra to see the obvious connections, if they exist.
2. I was asked this during a job interview and therefore assume the interviewer did not want me to appeal to theorems, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2227342/159872).

**The question:** Find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the $N \times N$ matrix

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
N & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1
\\
1 & N & 1 & \dots & 1
\\
1 & 1 & N & \dots & 1
\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & N
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is there an simple (interview-level) way to reason about this question? If I'm missing some obvious connection to the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175228/), I'm happy to learn and to then close this question.

Comment: write it as $N-1$ times identity plus the all-ones matrix $E$. You will find that the eigenvectors are the same as $E$, and the eigenvalues are $N-1$ plus the ones of $E$

Comment: It is sufficient to know two things to solve this question. (1). How to determine the eigenvalues/vectors of a matrix of pattern $ab^T$, where $a$ and $b$ are column vectors. (2). If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(A)$, where $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @Exodd, I don't follow such a short answer. Can you expand? Your comment seems the same as [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/175237/159872), but I don't understand phrases like the "characteristic of the ground field".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $E$ the all-ones $N\times N$ matrix. Notice that $A = (N-1)I + E$

Let now $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ be a base of eigenvectors for $E$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n$. Notice that
$$
Ev_i = \lambda_iv_i \implies Av_i = [(N-1)I + E]v_i = (N-1)v_i + \lambda_i v_i = (N-1+\lambda_i)v_i
$$
so the eigenvalues of $A$ are $N-1+\lambda_i$ with eigenvectors $v_i$.

You can now focus on finding eigevalues/vectors of $E$, that has been answered already

Answer (score 0):

An orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors is given by

$$ 
P=   \tiny
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  5  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  6  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  7  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  8  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  9   
\end{array}
\right)    
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{20}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{30}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{42}}  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{56}}  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{72}}  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{90}}   
\end{array}
\right).
$$

multiplied on the right by a diagonal matrix to adjust each column to vector length $1$

The two matrices, full size, are

$$ 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  5  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  6  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  7  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  8  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  9   
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$   
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{20}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{30}}  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{42}}  &  0  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{56}}  &  0  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{72}}  &  0   \\
  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{90}}   
\end{array}
\right).
$$