# Generating vectors of the face-centered cubic lattice

Tags: geometry, number-theory, quadratic-forms, integer-lattices

I can't find a reference for a set of generating vectors for the Tetrahedral-octahedral honeycomb lattice. I would like to know the "canonical" set and if possible a more general set described by angles (I think it would take three angles to completely describe it but I'm not sure on this either.)

Comment: http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/

Comment: So from the page... $<1,1,0>,<1,-1,0>,<0,1,-1>$ works?

Comment: show me the link to the specific page you like.

Comment: http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/D3.html ... I don't think I'm looking at the right one :)

Comment: Is the lattice you want the one with all integer points $(x,y,z)$ such that $x+y+z$ is even?

Comment: That sounds about right... I want any one that gives a sphere packing with kissing number $12$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. A3 or D3, called face centered cubic

http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/A3.html

Note that an extra dimension is required to avoid square roots in the basis coordinates. So, the three basis vectors are in $\mathbb R^4.$

$$  \langle 1,-1,0,0 \rangle  $$
$$  \langle 0,1,-1,0 \rangle $$
$$ \langle 0,0, 1,-1 \rangle $$

EEEEEEEDDDDDDIIIIIIIITTTTTTTTTT: Here is a somewhat cleaner answer, after I checked it in Schiemann's reduction. The lattice you want is the one I asked about, all integer points in $\mathbb R^3$ such that 
$$ x+y+z \; \; \; \;  \mbox{is even.}  $$

A basis can be given in the same dimension by
$$  \langle 0,1,1 \rangle  $$
$$  \langle 1,0,1 \rangle $$
$$ \langle 1,1, 0 \rangle $$
Notice that the squared lengths are 2, and the inner products are 1. So the matrix of inner products, the Gram matrix is

$$   
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
  2  &  1  &  1 \\
  1   &  2  &  1 \\
  1  &  1   &  2  
\end{array} 
  \right)  
  $$
The twelve lattice points nearest the origin, in this lattice, are
$$ (0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,0),  $$
$$ (0,-1,1), (-1,0,1), (-1,1,0),  $$
$$ (0,1,-1), (1,0,-1), (1,-1,0),  $$
$$ (0,-1,-1), (-1,0,-1), (-1,-1,0)  $$
for kissing number 12, as they are all the same distance from the origin, $\sqrt 2.$

Comment: Cool, thank you... Is it $<2,-1,0>,<-1,2,-1><0,-1,2>$?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos, no, that is the matrix of inner products, called the Gram matrix. I put a basis in the answer, three vectors in four dimensions, each squared length 2, inner products between are either 0 or $-1.$

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that. Ok that makes sense - thank you

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos, I edited in a second version that will probably be more useful to you. No square roots required, but all happening in $\mathbb R^3.$

Comment: Very nice. Is it typical to multiply them by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ to get them to have norm $1$? This doesn't change any of the properties of the lattice right?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos, if you want you can multiply by a constant, no change. If you want the radii of the packed spheres to be $1,$ you want the centers apart by 2, so multiply the basis vectors by $\sqrt 2$ to accomplish that. Do as seems useful.

Comment: Note that the determinant of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 1&1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ is $2$ (this is a special case of a [frequently asked question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/) ;-) which means that the parallelepiped the vectors span has volum $2$, as the fundamental region for this lattice, containing half the points of $\Bbb Z^3$, obviously should.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, well, yes.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen (and WillJagy) is the only requirement for a lattice to determine a valid sphere packing that they have to be the same norm away from eachother as they are from the origin?

Comment: Every lattice defines a regular stacking of spheres whose diameter equals the minimal distance between the lattice points. Calling it a [sphere packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing) suggests that one cannot (easily) increase the density by deforming the lattice while retaining the diameter; intuitively having touching spheres in many different directions gives an obstruction to such deformations. In the case of FCC, there are $12$ spheres touching any given one, and this is the largest number one can obtain in dimension $3$.