# Solve $J - X = JX$, where $J$ is the $n\times n$ matrix consisting of $1$s

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

So I am having a problem with a following problem:

> Let there be matrix $J\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, which has number $1$ everywhere.
>   Solve the equation for $X$: $J-X=JX$.

I think I have to apply a trace of a matrix, but I am not sure how, since you have a product of matrices on the right side.

Comment: What do you mean when you say “I have to apply a trace of a matrix”?

Comment: I think I have to use trace "operation", for solving of the equation, but I am not sure. Sorry for the confusion. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*: Rewrite the equation as
$$
(J+I)X=J
$$
and show that $\det(J+I)\neq 0$, so that
$$
X=(J+I)^{-1}J.
$$
There is no need of trace.

The determinant of a matrix with all non-diagonal coefficients equal to $1$ and diagonal $2$ has been computed at this site, see for example here:

[Determinant of a specially structured matrix ($a$'s on the diagonal, all other entries equal to $b$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/determinant-of-a-specially-structured-matrix-as-on-the-diagonal-all-other-e)

[Finding determinant for a matrix with one value on the diagonal and another everywhere else](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636909/finding-determinant-for-a-matrix-with-one-value-on-the-diagonal-and-another-ever)

Answer (score 3):

You may also write $J=ee^T$, where $e^T=(1,1,\ldots,1)$. The equation is then equivalent to $ee^T-X=ee^TX$ or $X=e(e^T-e^TX)$. Let $v^T=e^T-e^TX$. Then $X=ev^T$ and $v^T=e^T-e^TX=e^T-e^Tev^T=e^T-nv^T$. Hence $v^T=\frac{1}{n+1}e^T$ and $X=ev^T=\frac{1}{n+1}ee^T=\frac{1}{n+1}J$.

Comment: In what form is $v^T$ here?

Comment: @david1201 What do you mean?

Comment: I am not sure why did you use $v^T$ and how does this matrix looks? Sorry, I have just started with learning linear algebra this week.

Comment: @david1201 $v^T$ is defined to be $e^T-e^TX$. So, it's a row vector.