# What is the value of the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

\begin{vmatrix}
 a & b & b & \dots & b \\ 
 b & a & b & \dots & b \\ 
 b & b & a & \dots & b \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 b & b & b &   & a\\
 \end{vmatrix}

I still have no idea how to solve this determinant, please help me if you can:)

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/determinant-of-a-specially-structured-matrix).