# Find the inverse of the $n \times n$ matrix with ones on the main diagonal and $a$ off the main diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I want to find the inverse of this $n\times n$ matrix, assuming it is invertible. The condition of invertible is discussed at [Rank of the $n \times n$ matrix with ones on the main diagonal and $a$ off the main diagonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2181367).

Now assume it is invertible. I need to find the inverse.

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & a & \cdots & \cdots & a \\
a & 1 & a & \cdots & \cdots & a \\
a & a & 1 & a & \cdots & a \\
\vdots & \vdots & a& \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
a & a & a & \cdots  &\cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Sometimes they write capital $J$ for the square matrix with all entries $1.$   Then $J^2 = n J, \; $  and you can try to find $x,y$   so that $(xI + y J)  ( (1-a)I + a J) = I.$

Comment: @WillJagy so there is no closed form of the inverse matrix?

Comment: do me a favor, expand $(xI + yJ)((1-a)I + a J )$  and give the final coefficients of $I$ and $J$

Comment: @WillJagy I get 2 equations. $x(1-a)=1$ and $xa+y-ya+yan=0$

Comment: So, given $a \neq 1,$   what are $x$   and $y?$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2299977/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/561047/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2318984/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ {\bf M}_n (a) := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & a & \dots & a & a\\ a & 1 & a & \dots & a & a\\ a & a & 1 & \dots & a & a\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\ a & a & a & \dots & 1 & a\\ a & a & a & \dots & a & 1\end{bmatrix} = (1-a) {\bf I}_n + a {\bf 1}_n {\bf 1}_n^{\top} $$

Using [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula),

$$ {\bf M}_n^{-1} (a) = \cdots = \color{blue}{\frac{1}{1 - a} \left( {\bf I}_n - \frac{a}{1 + (n-1) a} {\bf 1}_n {\bf 1}_n^{\top} \right)} $$

which is the matrix that Greg obtained via other means.

Answer (score 1):

If $\def\o{{\tt1}}J$ is the $(n\times n)$ all-ones matrix, then $P=\frac{\o}nJ$ is a projector, i.e. $P^2=P.$

There is a general formula for functions of such matrices:
$$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\l{\lambda}
\def\LR#1{\:\left[#1\right]}
f(\l P+\b I) = f(\l+\b)\,P + f(\b)\,(I-P)
$$
The matrix in question can be written as
$$\eqalign{
A &= aJ + (\o-a)\,I \\
 &= (an)\,P + (\o-a)\,I \\
 &\equiv \l P + \b I \\
}$$
Choosing $\:f(A)=A^{-1}\:$ yields
$$\eqalign{
A^{-1} &= \frac{P}{\l+\b} + \frac{I-P}{\b} \\
 &= \frac{\o}{\b}\LR{I-\frac{\l P}{\l+\b}} \\
 &= \frac{\o}{\o-a}\LR{I-\frac{aJ}{an-a+\o}} \\
}$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It's from Chapter 1 of Higham's _Functions of Matrices_ $\,$ (I can't remember if it's shown as a theorem or as one of the problems in the appendix)

Comment: Thank you.  When you can find some time, please consider providing a reference to Higham's book.