# A formula for determinant of symetric matrix whose off-diagonal entries are $-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I've tried the determinant of matrices with the form
$$\left(
\begin{matrix}
x&-1&\cdots&-1\\
-1&x&\cdots&-1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&-1\\
-1&-1&\cdots&x
\end{matrix}
\right)_{n\times n}$$
i.e. with $x$ in the diagonal and $-1$ everywhere else.
I've always get $$(x+1)^n-n(x+1)^{n-1}=(x+1)^{n-1}(x-n+1)$$
for various $n$ and I think it is a correct formula.

I think by induction will be a way but I don't know how. Any variant or counterexample are welcome.

Comment: Good job. Nothing special about $-1$ though. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86644/.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Denote $D_n$ this determinant for an $n\times n$ matrix. Subtracting the second column from the  first end expanding by the first column, we  obtain that
$$D_n=\begin{vmatrix}x+1&-1&-1&\dots&-1\\
-(x+1)&\phantom{-}x&-1&\dots&-1\\ 0&-1&\phantom{-}x&\dots&-1\\[-1ex]
\vdots&\phantom{-}\vdots&\phantom{-}\vdots&\dots&\phantom{-}\vdots\\0&-1&-1&\dots&\phantom{-}x\end{vmatrix}
=(x+1)D_{n-1}+(x+1)\begin{vmatrix}-1&-1&\dots&-1\\
 -1&\phantom{-}x&\dots&-1\\[-1ex]
\phantom{-}\vdots&\phantom{-}\vdots&\dots&\phantom{-}\vdots\\-1&-1&\dots&\phantom{-}x\end{vmatrix}.$$
Now in the last determinant, the first row is the sum ot two rows
$$\begin{pmatrix}x &-1&\dots&-1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-x-1&0&\dots&0\end{pmatrix},$$
so that, by multilinearity
\begin{align}
&\begin{vmatrix}-1&-1&\dots&-1\\
 -1&\phantom{-}x&\dots&-1\\[-1ex]
\phantom{-}\vdots&\phantom{-}\vdots&\dots&\phantom{-}\vdots\\-1&-1&\dots&\phantom{-}x\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}x&-1&\dots&-1\\
 -1&\phantom{-}x&\dots&-1\\[-1ex]
\phantom{-}\vdots&\phantom{-}\vdots&\dots&\phantom{-}\vdots\\-1&-1&\dots&\phantom{-}x\end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}x+1&0&\dots&0\\
 -1&\phantom{-}x&\dots&-1\\[-1ex]
\phantom{-}\vdots&\phantom{-}\vdots&\dots&\phantom{-}\vdots\\-1&-1&\dots&\phantom{-}x\end{vmatrix}\\[1ex]
&= D_{n-1}-(x+1)\begin{vmatrix}
\phantom{-}x&\dots&-1\\[-1ex]
\phantom{-}\vdots&\dots&\phantom{-}\vdots\\-1&\dots&\phantom{-}x\end{vmatrix}
=D_{n-1}-(x+1)D_{n-2},
\end{align}
whence the recurrence relation:
$$D_n=2(x+1)D_{n-1}-(x+1)^2D_{n-2}.$$