# Determining the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of a symmetric symbolic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I am having trouble finding the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of symmetric symbolic matrices. The matrices given are as follows:

> $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} α & -β & -β \\ -β & α & -β \\ -β & -β & α \end{pmatrix} ,\qquad B = \begin{pmatrix} α & -β & -β & -β \\ -β & α & -β & -β \\ -β & -β & α & -β \\ -β & -β & -β & α \end{pmatrix} $$
>
> (1) Find all eigenvalues of both.
>
> (2) Find the eigenspaces of both.
>
> (3) Find the algebraic multiplicity and the geometric multiplicity of every eigenvalue of both.
>
> (4) Justify if the matrices are diagonalizable.

For previous problems I have calculated the determinant of the matrix subtraced by lambda multiplied by the identity matrix and set the determinant equal to zero to solve for lambda (obtaining the eigenvalues). However, I feel like some properties of symmetric matrices might make these problems easier than completing such lengthy and complex calculations. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86644/339790

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of shortcuts.

Looking at A.

All of the rows sum to $\alpha - 2\beta$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\1 \end {bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector, with $\alpha - 2\beta$ as the corresponding eigenvalue.

And consider $\lambda = \alpha + \beta$

Then $A - \lambda I = \begin{bmatrix} -\beta &-\beta &-\beta\\-\beta &-\beta &-\beta\\-\beta &-\beta &-\beta\end{bmatrix}$

$\alpha + \beta$ is a doubled eigenvalue.

A similar analysis can be done to matrix $B.$

$\alpha - 3\beta, \alpha + \beta$ appear to be the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4):

If $\beta=0$, then the $\alpha$ is the only eigenvalue and any non-zero vector is an eigenvaector.

Now, we can focus on $\beta \ne 0$.

The row sums is the same, hence $\alpha - (n-1)\beta$ is an eigenvalue. The all one vector is an eigenvector.

Also, when $\alpha-\lambda = -\beta$, the matrix is singular and the rank is $1$, $\alpha + \beta$ is an eigenvalue. This eigenspace has dimension $n-1$. You can consider eigenvector of the form of $e_1-e_j, j=2, \ldots, n.$

Symmetric matrices are diagonalizable.