# Show that $\det(A_n) =(a-1)^{n-1}(a+n-1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, symmetric-matrices

Show that $\det(A_n) =(a-1)^{n-1}(a+n-1)$ with K as a field and $ n \in N$

$ A_n = \begin{pmatrix} a & 1 & 1& 1 & ... & 1 \\ 1 & a & 1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & a & 1 & ... & 1 \\ ...& ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ 1 & ... & ... & ... & ... & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & ... & ... & 1 & a \end{pmatrix} \in K^{nxn}$

So i subtract everything with the first column like this

$ A_n = \begin{pmatrix} a & 1 & 1& 1 & ... & 1 \\ 1-a & a-1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 1-a & 0 & a-1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ ...& ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ 1-a & ... & ... & ... & ... & 0 \\ 1-a & 0 & ... & ... & 0 & a-1 \end{pmatrix} \in K^{nxn}$

And then i use Laplace on this

$\det(A_n)= a \cdot (a-1)^{n-1}+ \det\begin{pmatrix}  1-a & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 1-a & a-1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ ...& ... & ... & ... & ... \\ 1-a & ... & ... & ... & 0 \\ 1-a & ... & ... & 0 & a-1 \end{pmatrix} + 0$

So $\det\begin{pmatrix}  1-a & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 1-a & a-1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ ...& ... & ... & ... & ... \\ 1-a & ... & ... & ... & 0 \\ 1-a & ... & ... & 0 & a-1 \end{pmatrix} $ got to be $(n-1)(a-1)^{n-1}$ if my calculation is correct. But i can't find a way to 'show' it.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/81360).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom which one exactly?

Comment: They are all essentially the same, but [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86644/81360) (fifth on the list) is probably the easiest to follow

Comment: thanks! @Omnomnomnom