# A simple $n\times n$ system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Can anyone provide the analytical solution of the following $n\times n$ system of linear equations

$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
 a & -b & -b & ... & -b\\
 -b & a & -b & ... & -b\\
 -b & -b & a & ... & -b\\
  : &  : & : & ... & : \\
  : & : & : & ... &: & \\
 -b & -b & -b & ... & a \\
 \end{pmatrix}}_{A}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
:\\
:\\
x_n
\end{pmatrix}}_{X}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3\\
:\\
:\\
y_n
\end{pmatrix}}_{Y}
$
where $A_{(n\times n)}$ is a symmetric matrix and $a$, $b$, $y_i$ are positive real numbers.

Note: I would appreciate if someone could provide more details about the theory of eigenvalues-eigenvectors related to the solutuion of a linear system of eaquations.

Comment: It may not work, but what I would try : see for $n=2$ and $n=3$ if you can guess a pater for the caracteristic polynomial. And if yes, try to prove it by induction. 2) Diagonalise the matrix. 3) Conclude.

Comment: Thanks but I would like someone to provide a proof with at least some steps. I do not reme,ber this whole theory of solving such a system of linear equations. The last time I faced this was as an undergraduate back in 2008...If you could give some details by writing a proof I would appreciate it!

Comment: The determinant of your matrix $A$ is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/determinant-of-a-specially-structured-matrix-as-on-the-diagonal-all-other-e). So you can solve $Ax=b$ by $x=A^{-1}b$, for the case where $\det(A)\neq 0$. Otherwise it is easy, too.

Comment: All numbers are deifferent of zero, so... I conjecture that $det(A)\neq 0$

Comment: You don't have to make a conjecture, just read the duplicate and compute the determinant! There is a formula.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde thank you very much, but you don't mind If I take my time and w8 if someone has to give a full solution...no offence...

Comment: Don't worry. I just wanted to help you, and this is already the full solution in the duplicate. Your solution is $x=A^{-1}b$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120750/discussion-between-nav89-and-dietrich-burde).

Comment: In the duplicate the rows are reduced in an upper triangle matrix solve for $x_2, x_3, \cdots x_n $ you will get $x_1$ and you are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your equations as
$$
\left((a+b)I-b\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T\right)x=y\ ,$$
where $\ \mathbb{1}\ $ is the column vector whose entries are all $1$.  Multiplying this equation on the left by the row vector $\ \mathbb{1}^T\ $ gives
\begin{align}
(a+b)\mathbb{1}^Tx-b\mathbb{1}^T\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^Tx&=\mathbb{1}^Ty\\
&=\big(a-(n-1)b\big)\mathbb{1}^Tx\ ,\\
\hspace{-18em}\text{or}\\
\mathbb{1}^Tx&=\big(a-(n-1)b\big)^{-1}\mathbb{1}^Ty\ ,
\end{align}
provided $\ a-(n-1)b\ne0\ $. Now rewriting the first equation above as
$$
(a+b)x=y+b\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^Tx\ ,
$$
and substituting $\ \big(a-(n-1)b\big)^{-1}\mathbb{1}^Ty\ $ for $\ \mathbb{1}^Tx\ $ gives
\begin{align}
x&=\left(\frac{1}{a+b}\right)y+\left(\frac{b}{(a+b)\big(a-(n-1)b\big)}\right)\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^Ty\\
&=\left(\left(\frac{1}{a+b}\right)I+\left(\frac{b}{(a+b)\big(a-(n-1)b\big)}\right)\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T\right)y\ ,
\end{align}
provided $\ (a+b)\ne0\ $, which gives you the solution to your problem.

Comment: what is $b_{11}^{T}$ can you clarify this a little?

Comment: There is no $\ b_{11}^T\ $ anywhere in my answer, so I'm not sure I understand your question.  The column vector $\ \mathbb{1}\ $ is $$\pmatrix{1\\1\\\vdots\\1}\ ,$$ so
$$
b\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T=\pmatrix{b&b&\dots&b\\
           b&b&\dots&b\\
           \vdots&\vdots&\dots&\vdots\\
            b&b&\dots&b}\ .
$$

Comment: What do you mean by saying that ``if you can find an expression for $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^nx_i\ $ in terms of $\ y\ $". What kind of expression? The problem has the aforementioned formulation in its simple case...Could you give me more details ore answer with respect to my problem?

Comment: What I mean by "find an expression for $\sum_\limits{i=1}^nx_i$ in terms of $y$" is "express $\sum_\limits{i=1}^nx_i$ as a function of $y$".   In fact, since the equations are linear, you can expect to be able to express $\sum_\limits{i=1}^nx_i$ as a *linear* function of $y$, and my answer outlined one way to do  this.  I don't understand the rest of your question.  The first equation in my  answer is simply a restatement of your problem in a form which is easier to see how to solve.   But in any case,I have now revised the answer to include the full solution.

Comment: Everything is ok! Sorry if I confused you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use linear combinations in the main matrix:

- Take every line (except the first) minus the first:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 a & -b & -b & ... & -b\\
 -(a+b) & a+b & 0 & ... & 0\\
 -(a+b) & 0 & a+b & ... & 0\\
  : &  : & : & ... & : \\
  : & : & : & ... &: & \\
 -(a+b) & 0 & 0 & ... & a+b \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

- Now sum at the first column, the sum of the other columns:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 a-(n-1)b & -b & -b & ... & -b\\
 0 & a+b & 0 & ... & 0\\
 0 & 0 & a+b & ... & 0\\
  : &  : & : & ... & : \\
  : & : & : & ... &: & \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & a+b \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

The matrix is of type: linear combination of the identity and a rank $1$ matrix, the latter being the matrix all of whose entries are $-b$, call it $B$. Then $B$ is easily diagonalisable, with an $n-1$ dimensional kernel (eigenspace for $0$) given by the equation $x_1+\dots+x_n=0$, and a $1$ dimensional other eigenspace, spanned by $(1,1,\ldots,1)$, whose eigenvalue for $B$ equals $-nb$. We have $A=B+(a+b)I_n$; the eigenspaces of $B$ are also eigenspaces for $A$, but with eigenvalues $\lambda=a+b$ respectively $\mu=-nb+a+b=a+(1-n)b$.

The linear problem is easy to solve on each eigenspace: on the $n-1$ dimensional eigenspace $A$ acts by multiplication by $\lambda$ and, provided $\lambda\neq0$, the solution will be $X=\frac1\lambda Y$, while on the $1$-dimensional eigenspace $A$ acts by multiplication by $\lambda$ and, provided $\mu\neq0$, the solution will be $X=\frac1\mu Y$. For the general solution one can decompose $Y$ into its projections $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ on the two eigenspaces, and provided both $\lambda=a+b$ and $\mu=a+(1-n)b$ are nonzero one can find the solution by adding the solutions associated to $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. One has $Y_2=\frac{(y_1+\cdots+y_n)}n(1,1,\ldots,1)$ and $Y_1=Y-Y_2$; the general solution then is $X=\frac1\lambda Y_1+\frac1\mu Y_2$. Working this out explicitly is a bit messy, but straightforward.

Here is a concrete example if you find this too abstract. Take $n=5$, $a=2$ and $b=1$. Then neither $\lambda=a+b=3$ nor $\mu=a+(1-n)b=-2$ is zero, so the problem is solvable for all $Y$. Take for instance $Y=(3,-1,2,5,-4)$, it decomposes as the sum of a multiple $Y_2$ of $(1,1,1,1,1)$ by the scalar $\frac{3-1+2+5-4}5=1$, and a vector $Y_1=Y-Y_2=(2,-2,1,4,-5)$ whose sum of coordinates is $0$. The solution for $X$ then is
$\frac1\lambda Y_1+\frac1\mu Y_2=\frac13(2,-2,1,4,-5)-\frac12(1,1,1,1,1)=\frac16(1,-7,-1,5,-13)$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120823/discussion-on-answer-by-marc-van-leeuwen-a-simple-n-times-n-system-of-linear-e).