# Rank of a matrix with identical diagonal, upper triangle, and lower triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, toeplitz-matrices

I'm trying to figure out when the matrix below is full rank or non-singular. All the elements in the upper triangle (non-diagonal) are equal to $a$, elements in the lower triangle are equal to $c$, and diagonal elements are all $b$.
Also, $a > b > c$, and $b$ can be assumed not to be zero if it helps.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b      & a & a     & \dots  & a      \\
c      & b & a   & \dots  & a      \\
c      & c & b   & \dots  & a      \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c      & c      & c  & \dots &    b 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is such matrix always full rank? If not, can we make it full rank by making extra assumptions on the elements?

I appreciate any help with this!

Comment: To answer a part of your question: can it be made full rank? An obvious choice is $c=0$.

Comment: @AnuragA Right right; Thanks. I'm still hoping for full rank without extra assumption though.

Comment: Consider the $2{\times}2$ case with $b^2=ac$.

Comment: If $a = c$, then take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86644/339790)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks, that can give me some ideas. In my case though, $a$ is greater than $c$.